# Bootstrap 2 modal action not work

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

when user click delete button then a modal show and when user take action yes then action will be given url.But it not work

my code

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#deleteBtn", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
     var link = $(this).attr('data-adid');
    console.log($("#myModal btn-success a"));
     $("#myModal .btn-success a").attr('href',link);
     $(".modal").modal("show");
});
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Heads Up!
                     <p>What you are doing will delete a data!</p></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="" >Delete</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


        print'<td><button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" id="deleteBtn" data-target="#myModal" data-adid=?a=about&adid='.$cd[$i][0].'>Delete Item</a></button></td>';
```

here when user click to Delete Item Button then modal sho .when user click modal delete button then it take action to `?a=about&adid='.$cd[$i][0].'`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

1. Your data attribute you are trying to get a value from is malformed it's not wrapped in quotes "" should read
   `data-adid="?a=about&adid='.$cd[$i][0].'">'`
2. You wrapped a link inside button element. You need to set a link as a link and just style it as a button. Button element is used for forms rather than links.

   `<a href="" class="btn btn-success">Delete</a>`

So you would need to use a link as 
    `$('#myModal .btn-success').attr('href', link);`

Also you do not need to use 
    `e.preventDefault(); and e.stopPropagation();`

but rather throw  `return false;`